# Create Persistent Queries in Control Center?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I deployed Kafka from here https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.3.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml. But now I can't understand how to create persistent query. All I see is the init page:

[image]

In documentation https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/ksql.html it is not said how to get access.

What do I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: Click the button? Run a `CREATE STREAM` query?

Comment: that button leads to a recipes cookbook https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/

Comment: Okay. Did you search the docs? https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/cloud-quickstart/ksql.html#write-persistent-queries Basically, it's not clear what "access" you're looking for, or if you have actually written any query by clicking the "KSQL Editor" tab

Comment: Oh, my misunderstanding. You're right. Need to use CREATE STREAM. Thanks! Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a section of the KSQL documentation on [Persistent Queries](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/cloud-quickstart/ksql.html#write-persistent-queries)

You can write them in the "KSQL Editor" tab of Control Center

When running, they should appear in the "Running Queries" tab